# Visual basic - Incrementing the score

Tags: vb.net

```
    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Dim Query As String
    Dim connection As MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
    Dim item As Object
    Try
        item = InputBox("What is the item?", "InputBox Test", "Type the item here.")
        If item = "shoe" Then
            Dim connStr As String = ""
            Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
            connection.Open()
            Query = "select * from table where username= '" & Login.txtusername.Text & " '"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, connection)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
            If (READER.Read() = True) Then
                Query = "UPDATE table set noOfItems = noOfItems+1, week1 = 'found' where username= '" & Login.txtusername.Text & "'"
                Dim noOfItems As Integer
                Dim username As String
                noOfItems = READER("noOfItems") + 1
                username = READER("username")
                MessageBox.Show(username & "- The number of items you now have is: " & noOfGeocaches)
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Unlucky, Incorrect item. Please see hints. Your score still remains the same")

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try
```

I finally got the message box to display! but now my code does not increment in the database, can anybody help me please :D

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have typo in your select query. You are adding a space after the username value. By the way an sql string should be executed by a MySqlCommand if you want it to have any effects on your table. And this leads to another problem. Cannot use a command while a datareader is open

Comment: Also, why you increment a field named _noOfItems_ and then try to display the value of _noOfGeocaches_?

Comment: Hello @Steve I appreciate the help! I have sorted the query typo! and changed the variable to noOfItems (think that was a typo). However still doesn't increment in the database. I will look into mysqlcommand a bit more, if you have any idea, on how about to go around this problem, feel free to correct my code :)

Comment: @Steve If i switch the two queries around, i notice that the database increments the value, however then the message box does not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing your typos (space after the login textbox and name of the field retrieved) you are still missing to execute the sql text that updates the database.

Your code could be simplified understanding that an UPDATE query has no effect if the WHERE condition doesn't find anything to update. Moreover keeping an MySqlDataReader open while you try to execute a MySqlCommand will trigger an error in MySql NET connector. (Not possible to use a connection in use by a datareader). We could try to execute both statements in a single call to ExecuteReader separating each command with a semicolon and, of course, using a parameter and not a string concatenation

```
' Prepare the string for both commands to execute
Query = "UPDATE table set noOfItems = noOfItems+1, " & _ 
        "week1 = 'found' where username= @name; " & _
        "SELECT noOfItems FROM table WHERE username = @name"

' You already know the username, don't you?
Dim username = Login.txtusername.Text

' Create the connection and the command inside a using block to
' facilitate closing and disposing of these objects.. exceptions included
Using connection = New MySqlConnection(connStr)
Using COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, connection)
    connection.Open()

    ' Set the parameter value required by both commands.
    COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username

    ' Again create the reader in a using block
    Using READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        If READER.Read() Then
            Dim noOfItems As Integer
            noOfItems = READER("noOfItems")
            MessageBox.Show(username & "- The number of items you now have is: " & noOfItems )
        End If
   End Using
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: You genious! I really appreciate this, it works like a charm, and I will take time understand this code :)

Comment: Also i replaced all the using's with dim's and still works just as fine.. I get an error with the using function

Comment: @mr-c Format your code efficiently? Maybe it will compile.